# Javascript call method doesn't have same context

Tags: javascript

Trying to learn JavaScript `call` method:

I wrote these two code examples:

```
//Example 1 start

function myName(){
  console.log(this.name)//Roger
  console.log(roger.name)//Roger
}

let roger = {
  name: 'Roger',
}
myName.call(roger)

//Example 1 end


//Example 2 start

function yourName(){
  console.log(this.name);//Charlie
  console.log(charlie.name);//ReferenceError: charlie is not defined
}

function hisName(){
  let charlie = {
    name: 'Charlie'
  }
  yourName.call(charlie);
}
hisName();

//Example 2 end
```

I am little confused as to why in Example 2, `yourName` function doesn't have the same context for `charlie.name`  as `roger.name` does in `myName` function. `this` context seem to be working for both examples. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `roger`  is in `global scope` so the variable `roger` in function myName() is accessible.

However, the variable `charlie` is in `local scope` that is bound to function hisName() so the variable `charlie`in function yourName() can not be accessible.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But how is this any different than passing a simple variable from one function to another? I mean I could just remove the ".call" method and pass the charlie object to yourName function. And I would have access to charlie object. So why is that I can't pass the charlie object using the .call() method? Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

The symbol "charlie" is not in scope in the `yourName()` function. Scope is a static thing; the "charlie" variable is declared in a different function and so it's totally invisible inside `yourName()`.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But how is this any different than passing a simple variable from one function to another? I mean I could just remove the ".call" method and pass the charlie object to yourName function. And I would have access to charlie object. So why is that I can't pass the charlie object using the .call() method? Thanks..

Comment: Passing a variable means passing the **value** of the variable. How, in example 2, is the function supposed to "know" that the value passed into the function happened to be the value of a variable called "charlie"? What if it was called "thomas" or "frederick"? There is no real relationship between a variable and a value it happens to have, even when that value is a reference to some object.